# Proper Use of <address> tag

Tags: html

I'm updating some pages with HTML5 elements and I'm a little confused about the `address` tag.

I've read the MDN pages and found the following:

> The HTML  Element may be used by authors to supply contact
>   information for its nearest  or  ancestor; in the
>   latter case, it applies to the whole document.

The content in question that I'm working on contains a phone number, address, and social media links of this organization in the footer of each page. This organization doesn't have a specific person as a contact, but a general number and address to be displayed on each page.

1. Given the general nature of this contact information, is it appropriate to use the `<address>` tag?
2. Is it okay to include social media links or are these beyond the semantic scope of this tag?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same doc, and https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#the-address-element, state that it can have arbitrary content, with the restrictions noted.

It further states that the *only* information that should be contained in it is related contact information, e.g., it should *not* be used to:

> [...] represent arbitrary addresses (e.g. postal addresses), unless those addresses are in fact the relevant contact information.

The spec doesn't address "social media", so I guess this is opinion: if the social media links are an "approved" means of contact, those links would fall under the purview of the tag.